# @RequestMapping with multiple URL qualifying

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, request-mapping

Thanks for your reply.Let me rephrase the question again.Suppose if there are two @ RequestMapping qualifying for different controller then how it works below is the code.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(/user/*)
public class MyController{
//some methods
}
@Controller
@RequestMapping(/user/file)
public class MyController2{
//some methods
}
```

So from above two methods if we request

> URL(www.xyz.com/myapp/user/file/show)
>   Where xyz is some domain ,myapp is my contextroot so in this case both controllers mentioned above is qualifying so which one will be selected.

Comment: Not sure that is what you meant for, but `@RequestMapping` does work for multiple urls. For example: `@RequestMapping(value = { "/info", "/information", "/inf" })`

Comment: I have rephrased the question again please help.